# Insert data into nested table plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Well, I want to insert data from a table into a nested table.

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  TYPE employee_type IS TABLE OF employees.salary%TYPE;
  emps employee_type;
  i NUMBER(5) := 100;
  sal employees.salary%TYPE;

BEGIN
LOOP
SELECT salary INTO sal FROM employees WHERE employees.employee_id = i;
    emps := employee_type(sal);
    i := i + 1;

EXIT WHEN i > 110;
END LOOP;
SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emps.count);
```

This is my code but when I do `SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emps.count);` I only get 1 but it should be 10 actually

Comment: This is not a nested table; it as simply a collection. A nested table is when you have a collection stored (nested) within an SQL table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
emps := employee_type(sal);
```

initializes the collection with a single element containing the salary. Every time you do this, you erase the existing collection and replace it with a new one consisting of one element only again.

Instead, initialize the collection once and then extend it element by element:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE employee_type IS TABLE OF employees.salary%TYPE;
  emps employee_type := employee_type(); -- initializing the array right away
  i NUMBER(5) := 100;
  sal employees.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    SELECT salary INTO sal FROM employees WHERE employees.employee_id = i;
    emps.EXTEND(1); -- add one element
    emps(emps.COUNT) := sal; -- fill that element
    i := i + 1;
    EXIT WHEN i > 110;
  END LOOP;

  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emps.count);
END;
```

It is much easier though to bulk collect the values into the array (which also implicitly initialized the array).

```
DECLARE
  TYPE employee_type IS TABLE OF employees.salary%TYPE;
  emps employee_type;
  i NUMBER(5) := 100;
BEGIN
  SELECT salary BULK COLLECT INTO emps 
  FROM employees 
  WHERE employee_id BETWEEN i AND 110;

  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emps.count);
END;
```